# Set automapping for exchange-online SharedMailbox as default for all user

Tags: powershell, exchange, shared-mailbox

We have some migrated sharedmailboxes on a exchange online mailserver. When users get access to one of these mailboxes via mailbox delegation setup, these mailboxes do not appear automatically in their outlook.

I know there is a powershell script for enabling automapping for a single user for a mailbox.

```
Get-Mailbox "SharedMailbox" | Add-MailboxPermission -User UserXYZ -AccessRights FullAccess -AutoMapping:$TRUE
```

But is there a script or a setting, to enable automapping as a default for a mailbox?
So that all users, also new user that get access to the mailbox, will automatically get it displayed in their outlook?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge, you could achieve this goal in exchange on-prem via scripts agent, but in exchange online it seems cannot be achieved via scripts agent.

If you want to enables Outlook automapping on mailboxes where users have been given full access rights, you may need seek for a script expert to do this. For more details: [Enable Outlook Automapping for Exchange mailboxes](https://blog.expta.com/2019/01/enable-outlook-automapping-for-exchange.html)